# Instagram video fetching not working?

Tags: php, instagram

I am trying to show video from instagram,but its not working for me.I am giving the code below:

```
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
        <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
        <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Above code is performing well for image,any idea how to display video.If possible than suggest me about pagination also?

Comment: Tried to `<?php echo` instead of `<?=`. Show the source code of the generated page in the browser to see how the outcome of the html?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc of the API](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#) you can check if the media is an image or a video.

Then just check it before create your HTML, somethin like this should work:

```
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post) {
    if ($post->type == "image") { ?>
        <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
        <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?php $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
    <?php } 

    else { ?>
       <video width="640" height="480" controls="controls">
       <source src="<?= $post->videos->standard_resolution->url ?>" type="video/mp4">
       </video>


    <?}
} ?>
```

Comment: Its not working properly,video play pause button is not showing. x_vi_r

Comment: is the url correct ? I changed the video HTML code, plz have a try

Comment: Its now working,but I want only play and pause image at the top of the video.Not whole control.What to do?Thanks for your reply @ x_vi_r

Comment: You can do this with JS or CSS. Please consider to vote up  and accept answer :)